# Granting user access

Tags: mysql, zend-framework

We're developing a web app using the Zend framework and Mysql.

Currently, accounts are unique by email address. We want to be able to allow the admin of an account to grant access to the admin of another account. This person would then be a "user" of the linked account. The account holder would then log into their admin account and then select which linked account they want to access.

Please note: the access should only be one way. Account 1, who grants access to Account 2, should not be able to access account 2. Only account 2 can access account 1. If Account 1 wanted access to account 2, account 2 would then have to grant access to account 1.

What is the best method of going about this?

Comment: In plain English: Does this mean that you need to create groups of users?

Comment: Is this really mysql specific? Most web apps implement "accounts" at the app level and use the database only as a data store. As well, you seem to use user/admin in multiple ways in your question. Some more detail would be good, with better concrete examples. But in essence you seem to be talking about transitive permissions

Comment: Let me see if I can be more clear. An "admin" is the person who owns the account. A "user" is a person who is authorized to use the account but without admin permissions.

Lets say we have two accounts. Accounts are unique based on email address. 

Account 1 wants Account 2 to manage their account for them. In order for this to happen Account 1 has to authorize the other account. Doing so would allow Account 2 to log into their own account and then click on a link to manage Account 1. 

This concept is very similar to how Google Analytics and Google Adwords account management works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think trying to tie permissions to accounts is your problem, you need to add a second 'layer'. Let's stick with Google Analytics as the example:

Let's say Joe Bloggs wants to use Google Analytics. He first has to create a Google account (assuming he doesn't already have one). He then creates a Google Analytics account for his *site*. Say Joe then wants to give access to Jane Smith, let's assume she already has a Google account. To give her access all he is doing is giving her Google account access to his *site*, he's not giving her access to his Google account.

Zend_Acl is role based so let's try and apply ZF concepts to this example. The user management screens in GA allow you to give users either "View reports only" access, or "Account administrator". So you'd define a role in Zend_Acl for each of these access levels:

```
$acl = new Zend_Acl();
$acl->addRole(new Zend_Acl_Role('guest'));
$acl->addRole(new Zend_Acl_Role('admin'), 'guest');
```

the second parameter on addRole means the role should inherit all permissions from the other role specified. So what I've done above is define two roles: guest and admin; and said admin should inherit all permissions that guest has.

You then have your 'resources', which are the things that can be accessed. So we'll define one for reports, and one for user management:

```
$acl->add(new Zend_Acl_Resource('reports'));
$acl->add(new Zend_Acl_Resource('users'));
```

we'll then give 'guest' access to reports, and 'admin' access to users:

```
$acl->allow('guest', 'reports');
$acl->allow('admin', 'users');
```

then in the relevant controllers (or plugin, or wherever) you can check permissions:

```
public function reportsAction()
{
    [...]

    // assume $role contains the role of the currently logged in user
    if (!$acl->isAllowed($role, 'reports')) {
        // show a permissions error
    }
}

public function usersAction()
{
    [...]

    if (!$acl->isAllowed($role, 'users')) {
        // permissions error
    }
}
```

As far as storing this in MySQL goes, you just need a lookup table that links users, sites (in this example) and roles:

```
userID | siteID | role
   1       1      admin
   2       1      guest
```